# What should I do with this maybe meta question?

Tags: discussion, questions

I came across this question here: [Is it bad design for an app to read from STDIN twice with two EOFs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65452637/is-it-bad-design-for-an-app-to-read-from-stdin-twice-with-two-eofs?noredirect=1#comment115717255_65452637)

The OP talked about one of the previous questions, but yet the "bad design" is obviously in coding. What should I do? I flagged it for migration, but then I retracted it.

Comment: It's not a meta question, it's a question about programming that will likely get opinion based answers, and has been closed as such.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The linked question (on the main Stack Overflow) is *not* a meta post but a programming question (albeit off-topic for other reasons). It should *not* be migrated to meta since there's no meta discussion asked (e.g. how to improve the question, etc.).

Questions that link to other questions (e.g. OP's previous question) don't become meta questions automatically. In fact, sometimes it's *recommended* to link to other questions if it can add more context/background to the issue.

One of the deletion reasons on Very Low-Quality Review Queue is:

> **This is a different question posted as an answer**
>
> “If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the Ask Question button. ***Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.***”
>
> <sup>(emphasis added)</sup>